# R says "Cannot take a sample larger than the population" -- but I am not taking a sample larger than the population

Tags: r

I am trying to pick 3500 random observations from a set of 5655 observations. But when I do so, R is throwing a strange error, saying that "cannot take a sample larger than the population when 'replace = FALSE'"

I am trying to take a sample smaller than the population. Why is R throwing this error?

```
nrow(males)
[1] 5655
m = sample(males, 3500, replace = FALSE, prob = NULL)
```

> Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) :
> cannot take a sample larger than the population when 'replace = FALSE'

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You need to sample from the numbers, not from the data frame. Then use the results to get the sampled rows.

```
m <- males[sample(nrow(males), 3500, replace = FALSE, prob = NULL),]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use $ to select the specific column within your data set you want to sample from.
Ex: `m <- sample(dataframename$variable, 3500)`

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
males %>% sample_n(3500, replace = FALSE, prob = NULL)

#if you don't like the pipe notation, this works equally well
sample_n(males, 3500, replace = FALSE, prob = NULL)
```

Comment: I have never been able to get sample_n or slice_sample to work with dplyr - and I am experienced R dev......I have given up. Weirdest thing.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if you accidentally use `sample()` where you actually want to be using `sample_n()`.

#### Example

What you **don't** want

```r
iris %>% 
  sample(10)
# Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : 
#   cannot take a sample larger than the population when 'replace = FALSE'
```

Using `sample_n()` instead:

```r
library(dplyr)

iris %>% 
  sample_n(10)
#    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
# 1           4.6         3.6          1.0         0.2    setosa
# 2           5.4         3.7          1.5         0.2    setosa
# 3           5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2    setosa
# 4           6.7         3.3          5.7         2.1 virginica
# 5           6.2         3.4          5.4         2.3 virginica
# 6           4.3         3.0          1.1         0.1    setosa
# 7           5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9 virginica
# 8           5.8         2.8          5.1         2.4 virginica
# 9           6.8         3.2          5.9         2.3 virginica
# 10          7.6         3.0          6.6         2.1 virginica
```

Answer (score -1):

Change the replace from False to True

```
m = sample(males, 3500, replace = True, prob = NULL)
```

Comment: What if you don't want to sample with replacement?

Comment: Logical values in R are in all caps

Answer (score -1):

Change the replace from **FALSE** to **TRUE**

```
nrow(males) 
[1] 5655 
m = sample(males, 3500, replace = TRUE, prob = NULL)
```